# Where can I view a list of Facebook apps to install from?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I do not use Facebook very much but I remeber reading some documentation a long time ago about Facebook apps being available by third-party developers.

Where do I view the list and how can I browse and install some of these (just like Android and iPhone users can download and install apps from the respective play store or equivalent)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook currently lists games this way

Point your browser to https://www.facebook.com/games/

[image: Games for Facebook]

From there you should be able to search for other apps as well and send it to mobile to install.

[image: Instagram]

Comment: So basically all Facebook apps are games? What about other type of apps?

Comment: @JordanJamingsons Facebook tends to market mostly games. Other apps you search for like Instagram (above)

Comment: So basically from http://facebook.com/games I can also search the google play store and send apps to my Android device?

Comment: @JordanJamingsons No, you can only search games that are listed at facebook.com/games so if a developer chose not to list his game it wouldn't appear.

Comment: How does a developer go about listing his game. I actually have a few Android apps on the Google Play Store. I wouldn't mind being able to have them listed on FB as well. (NOTE: my apps don't have FB versions). Will I be able to list my apps on FB? Thanks.

Comment: @JordanJamingsons via https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/appcenter, no if your app does not have FB integration it will not be listed.